# General Triangle Inequality, distance from a point to a set

Tags: inequality, metric-spaces

I am trying with no luck to prove:

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $A$ a non-empty subset of $X$. For $x,y\in X$,
> prove that
> $$d(x,A) < d(x,y) + d(y,A)$$

Comment: You won't be able to prove this with strict inequality; for instance, take $A = \{y\}$. You need $\leq$.

Comment: Try drawing a picture of a set A with two points x and y outside it.

Comment: It will help if you have sitting in front of you the definition of distance from a point to a set.

Comment: I've drawn all the pictures. But doesn't it come down to some creative trick or using a fact about infimum?  I can't see it.

Answer (score 11):

If you have $\leq$ instead of $<$, then you have:

$d(x,A) = \inf_{z\in A} d(x,z)$. Now, say $z_0\in A$ and $y\in X$. Then $d(x,z_0)\leq d(x,y) + d(y, z_0)$. Taking infimum over all $z\in A$ of the left hand side, we obtain:

$$
d(x, A) = \inf_{z\in A}d(x,z) \leq d(x,z_0) \leq d(x,y) + d(y, z_0).
$$

Observe that $d(x, A)$ is now independent of $z_0$. Hence taking the infimum over all $z$ in $A$ of the right hand side, we get:

$$
d(x,A) \leq d(x,y) + \inf_{z\in A}d(y,z) = d(x,y) + d(y, A).
$$

Comment: Isn't there the possibility that d(y,A) < d(y,z0), in which case your last inequality doesn't necessarily hold?

Comment: @student'su if $a\le b_\alpha$ for all $\alpha$, then $a\le \inf_\alpha b_\alpha$.

Comment: I have a constant on the left, which is not smaller than the right hand side for ANY choice of $z_0\in A$. Now try proving rigorously that this is enough to conclude the proof as I did it above (hint: you can always chose a sequence $\{z_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in  $A$ such that $d(y,z_n)\rightarrow \inf_{z\in A}d(y,z)$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$).

Comment: @student : The definition itself of the infimum is the following ; the infimum is a lower bound which is greater than or equal to any other lower bound. Since $d(x,A)$ is a lower bound of $\{ d(x,y) + d(y,z_0) \, | \, z_0 \in A \}$, then it is less than or equal to the infimum. In other words, it's a triviality you shouldn't be worrying about.

Comment: Thanks all.  I understand.  I have no idea why this was hard for me.

Comment: @student: Most things in mathematics aren't easy or natural when you see them for the first time. It takes practice, no matter whether you're a student or a professional mathematician.

Comment: Elegant and short. Well done.

Answer (score 0):

One could also use the relation $|\inf_{x\in A}\{f(x)\}-\inf_{x\in A}\{g(x)\}|\leq \sup_{x\in A} \{|f(x)-g(x)|\}$, to prove that $|d(x,A)-d(y,A)|\leq d(x,y)$ (from which one gets the result) as follows:
$$
|d(x,A)-d(y,A)|=|\inf_{a\in A}\{d(x,a)\}-\inf_{a\in A}\{d(y,a)\}|\leq \sup_{a\in A} \{|d(x,a)-d(y,a)|\}
$$
and since by the triangle inequality we have: $|d(x,a)-d(y,a)|\leq d(x,y)$, (e.g. $d(x,a)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,a)$), then $d(x,y)$ is an upper bound of $|d(x,a)-d(y,a)|$ and so we have: $$\sup_{a\in A} \{|d(x,a)-d(y,a)|\}\leq d(x,y)$$
Q.E.D.

Answer (score 0):

let $c \in A$ arbitrary, by  the inverse triangle inequality
$$d(x,c)-d(c,y)\leq d(x,y)$$
and by definition of $d(x,A), d(y,B)$ we get
$$d(x,A)-d(y,A)\leq d(x,y) \Rightarrow d(x,A) \leq d(x,y)+d(y,A)$$