# A linear system optimization

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-geometry

Let $A: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^d$ be a matrix.
Let

$$\max_{\|y\|_2 \leq 1 } \min_{\|x\|_2 \leq R}\|Ax-y\|_2 = \epsilon\;.$$ (where $R$ is the radius of the norm ball that $x$ is constrained to).

Can we say the following
$$\max_{\|y\|_2 \leq t } \min_{\|x\|_2 \leq R}\|Ax-y\|_2 = O(t\epsilon) \;?$$
(where $O()$ hides some additive and mulitplicative constants).

EDIT:
As mentioned in the comments
the problem can be written as
$$\max_{y \in \mathcal{B}(1)}\|ty - \mathrm{Proj}_{Ax:x\in \mathcal{B}(R)}(ty)\|$$
Note the projection operation is on a closed convex set $\{Ax:x\in \mathcal{B}(R)\}$, which we define for brevity by $C$.
Thus the problem reduces to
$$\max_{y \in \mathcal{B}(1)}\|ty - \mathrm{Proj}_C(ty)\|\; .$$
Thus we have
$\max_{y \in \mathcal{B}(1)}\|y - \mathrm{Proj}_C(y)\| = \epsilon$
which by usual definition of the distance function
$d(y, C) \leq \epsilon$ for all $y \in  \mathcal{B}(1)$.
So if the triangle inequality holds true, then we have
$d(ty, C) \leq t\epsilon$ for all $y$ and the it is proved.

Using this link [General Triangle Inequality, distance from a point to a set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108337/general-triangle-inequality-distance-from-a-point-to-a-set?noredirect=1&lq=1)

we have
$$d(ty, C) \leq d(ty, (t-1)y) + d((t-1)y, (t-2)y)+ \ldots+ d(y, C)$$
$$\leq O(t\epsilon)$$

EDIT is this correct? Adding an edit to increase visibility

Comment: Seems feasible, maybe write it as $\max_{y \in \overline{B}(0,t)} \|y -\operatorname{proj}_{A \overline{B}(0,R)} y\|$.

Comment: Why isn't this a complete answer?

Comment: Still needs a little analysis :-).

Comment: Isn't the above the same as $t\max_{||y|| \leq 1}||y - proj (y)||$

Comment: Not quite. ${}$